# Exporting Y equation for Logistic Model with Categorical Variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have built a logistic model in R. 
As the system in which the data set is present – doesn’t support integration of any other application, I have to export the Equation of this model and use that Y equation to predict the outcome.
The problem is that my data set has many categorical variables and when the model is built, R will provide the coefficients only for n-1 factors. (for example if the variable has 4 factors – Q1, Q2, Q3 & Q4, in the logistic model the coefficients will be available only for 3 factors Q2, Q3 & Q4). In this case, how can I deal will the missing Factors coefficients for the variable.

Comment: The three coefficients are the differences to the base level, i.e.the coefficient for Q1 is 0.

Comment: It is happening to avoid you from the [dummy trap](https://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html). So, if you use a constant variable in your regression model while you have got N categorical variable (a.k.a: factor variable, dummy variable), you HAVE TO put N-1 dummies. R is just handling it for you !